# Configuration of ROS2 Slam Toolbox

Tags: ros2, slam, lidar

I am having trouble configuring SLAM toolbox to work well for my application. I have a very detailed laser scan, but it seems that a lot of that detail is not making it onto the map. For some context, I am converting the output of a 3D Lidar into a 2D subsection so the detection is better than something like a rpilidar. Firstly, it seems like the angular resolution of the toolbox is lower than that of my Lidar. This leads to some details getting lost. See Below.
[image: Clear detection of wall not updating the map]
I have been playing around with the parameters a lot, but cant seem to get it to include areas like this. Another issue I run into is once an area has been well mapped from afar, but map doesn't seem to want to update when the robot drive up closer. There is a section of ~1 foot of the red laser scan points that are not making into onto the map.
[image: Section of lasers can not making it onto the map]
Thank you for any help/direction.